# My wordpress site redirect me to my localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, web, dns

my wordpress site works fine with “www.” but when I delete “www” it redirects me to localhost  , I tried with .htacess but didn't work

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

please help

Comment: So _what_ did you try with .htaccess and what does _"didn't work"_ mean?

Comment: Did you transfer your site from localhost to live?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: yes from local to live , and change the urls in database and wordpress admin panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show your .htaccess. And remember that .htaccess redirects are cached in browser. Clear cache or open site in new anonymous tab after every change in it.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I have not enough reputation for comment)

Comment: thnks, i save my htaccess and access my site with another browser, it works, thnak you